# How to refactor out the urls from the model when notifying about comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

I have a simple polymorphic **comment** model defined as follows:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  if Rails.env.production?
    default_url_options[:host] = "www.livesite.org"
  else  
    default_url_options[:host] = "livesite.dev"
  end

  attr_accessible :content
  attr_accessible :commentable_id, :commentable_type
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :content

  after_create :subscribe_to, :notify_subscribers

  private

    def subscribe_to
      commentable.rdb[:subscribers].sadd user_id
    end

    def notify_subscribers
      subscriber_ids = commentable.rdb[:subscribers].smembers.to_a
      subscriber_ids.delete user_id.to_s
      # remove the author's id from the array
      subscribers = User.where(id: subscriber_ids)
      subscribers.each do |subscriber|
        subscriber.notifications.create(
          content:        "<a href='#{ user_url(user) }'>#{user.name}</a> commented about <a href='#{ polymorphic_url(commentable) }'>#{commentable.name}</a>",
          read:           false,
          notifyable:     commentable
        )
      end
    end

end
```

You can see I use a little Redis magic to create a number of subscribers to a particular commentable, but my question is how can I abstract out the `polymorphic_url` part on the model here.  It seems strange to have it at the model level.  Is there a better approach?  Having it here means I need to include the `url_helpers` and is making working with Capybara and testing a real palava.

For reference, Notification.rb is as follows:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :subject, :read, :user_id, :notifyable

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :notifyable, polymorphic: true

  default_scope order('created_at DESC')

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move that notify logic up into a service object ([read more here](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)).

```
- app
  - models
  - views
  - controllers
  - services # put service objects here
```

Your new service object would be solely responsible for performing the notification logic, you need to at least pass in your comment model, and include or dependency inject the url helper

```
class CommentNotificationService
  def initialize(comment, url_provider)
    @comment, @url_provider = comment, url_provider
  end
end
```

Instantiate it in your controller like:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    comment = Comment.new params[:comment]
    service = CommentNotificationService.new comment, Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    if comment.save
      service.do_the_work
    else
      ...
  end
end
```

Now in the service's `do_the_work` method you can do the same as your old model's `notify_subscribers` method. The dependency injection part isn't the best (specially how I wrote it out) but it's a good starting point. You could very well include the url_helpers in your service object the way you did in your model.

The service object approach leaves your model lean and easy to test by taking away the added responsibility of having to do the notify. Then you can easily test the notify logic.

Comment: Moving out into a service object is a great idea, and I've started doing this, however I can't see how this means I'm not using `polymorphic_url` in that service object?  This means I'm still running into the same problem with Capybara and Selenium whereby I don't always know the full domain/port the test is running on.  Any advice?

Comment: Oh for that you need to do what PinnyM said.

Comment: I ended up specifying the port Capybara was running by using `Capybara.server_port = 7787` which meant then in test.rb I could use `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "127.0.0.1:7787" }`

Answer (score 0):

These attributes should be set in the corresponding environment file (e.g. `config/environments/development.rb`):

```
config.after_initialize do
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'livesite.dev'
end
```

Do the same for your `production.rb` environment file with the corresponding hostname.